# Feasibility of Nested Directories on Android

Tags: android, navigation, directory

I'm currently developing an Android journal/diary application that allows the user to create entries and store them by day.
To accomplish this, I was considering having a folder for each day and a subfolder in each day folder for each entry.  This probably demonstrates that better:

day->journal entry->journal entry data
   ->other journal entry for that day->journal entry data
   -> etc.

Now, with a folder for each day I'm already at 365 directories, and possibly many more within those.
This makes me doubt feasibility of implementing so many subdirectories.

This comes with the caveat that I would not be going through EVERY directory at once, but at most loading perhaps 31 days to display on a calendar.

The final question is would my application be slowed to oblivion navigating large amounts of directories, or should I not even have to worry about that at all?
What's holding me back from just making SQL database solutions for the application is the fact that I know absolutely no SQL at the moment, and don't know how easy/quick it is to learn.

Help/comments/ideas are all appreciated
Thanks!

Comment: Can't comment on the folder structure performance, but your problem sounds like a prime candidate for a database.  I'd bite the bullet and learn about SQL and databases, it's not really that difficult.

Comment: any recommendations as to where to learn SQL from start to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean file system directories, i.e., on the SD card for example? If so, IMHO you 'really' don't want to do that - I've seen examples of this kind of 'filing' system go horribly wrong due to complexity.

I'd recommend some form of simple storage but with some form of indexing/cataloguing system which can be as simple as using date/time strings for file names.

Example - suppose the journal entries are simple text files, you could use a file name format such as `YYYYMMDD_XXX.txt` and simply save all files into one directory.

In this case XXX would be numeric characters from 001 -> 999 representing the entry 'number' allowing a possible 999 journal entries per day (more than enough). Using a year-month-day (YYYYMMDD) format would allow sorting of file name strings in a chronological order strengthened by XXX ("001" would come before "002" in an ascending string sort operation). It would also allow wildcard searches (all journal entry text files for a given month would start "YYYYMM".

The above is a simple example and I'd probably go at least one step further and use a single XML file for each day. A format such as...

```
<journal date=20110213>
    <entry number=001>
        <data topic=My journey to work>On my way to work today blah...</data>
    </entry>
    <entry number=002>
        <data topic=Morning meeting>Fell asleep, blah...</data>
    </entry>
</journal>
```

I would then omit the XXX from the filename and just use `YYYYMMDD.xml`.

OK, just a couple of angles (I could ramble on but I won't).

You mention using a SQL DB - in general, basic SQL is quite simple but it can get as complex as you're prepared to go. For your requirements, you could get away with using a single table with a relatively small number of columns and the DB engine would handle a great deal of the 'filing' system for you. I'd recommend you try a few introductory SQL tutorials before deciding which way to go.